# Could not read from remote repository: Installing Stencil CLI from GitHub

Tags: node.js, git, npm, bigcommerce

Attempting to install a github repository called Stencil CLI for a BigCommerce website dev.

Keep getting the following in Windows 10 Powershell when calling npm to clone stencil repo to local directory

[image]

npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (git@github.com:bigcommerce/stencil-cli)

npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce/stencil-cli Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\stencil\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_git-remotes\git-github-com-bigcommerce-stencil-cli-5691b922'...

npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce/stencil-cli Host key verification failed.

npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce/stencil-cli fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce/stencil-cli

npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce/stencil-cli Please make sure you have the correct access
rights

npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:bigcommerce/stencil-cli and the repository exists.

npm ERR! addLocal Could not install bigcommerce/stencil-cli

npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\stencil\bigcommerce\stencil-cli'

npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:

npm ERR!     http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues

npm ERR! or email it to:

npm ERR!     npm-@googlegroups.com

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@bigcommerce/stencil-cli"

npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\stencil

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.16

npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.8

npm ERR! path C:\Users\stencil\bigcommerce\stencil-cli

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! errno 34

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\stencil\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: Are you just running `npm i -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli`, or are you doing something with `git clone` manually here? Looks like the SSH git URL is being used here, you may need to configure your git client with SSH. Try running through these steps (In git bash, not powershell.) https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: I'm running "npm -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli"  This is what is listed on the dev write up page for bigcommerce to clone their stencil repo.

Comment: Have you configured your git client to work over SSH? You need to generate an SSH key to associate with your git client. Did you try to follow the link I showed you?

Comment: I have not done so. That's for the tip. That will be my next thing to tackle.

Comment: Still getting a Host key verification failed.  I have verified with git-bash that I have generated a public SSH and have added it to my github account and its still being denied when cloning the repo